# Angular named router outlet doesn't work as expected

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, router-outlet, ng-component-outlet

I've an angular project with the following routing structure, starting from the app root:

```
  // app-routing.module.ts
  const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: 'admin',
      loadChildren: () => import('./features/admin/admin.module').then((m) => m.AdminModule)
    },
  ];
  // Import and export...

  // admin-rounting.module.ts
  const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: 'admin',
      component: ShellComponent,
      children: [
        {
          path: 'editor',
          loadChildren: () => import('./editor/editor.module').then((m) => m.EditorModule),
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
  // Import and export...

  // editor-routing.module.ts
  const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: '',
      component: EditorComponent,
    },
    {
      path: 'view-profile',
      component: ViewProfileComponent,
      outlet: 'profile',
    },
    {
      path: 'edit-profile',
      component: EditProfileComponent,
      outlet: 'profile',
    },
  ];
  // Import and export...
```

The root outlet it's in the `AppComponent`, afterwards the `ShellComponent` contains another router outlet that is passed as content to a `SidebarComponent` that displays it in a `mat-sidenav-content`, something like this:

```
    // app.component.html
    <router-outlet><router-outlet>

    // shell.component.html
    <sidebar>
        <router-outlet outlet></router-outlet>
    </sidebar>

    // sidebar.component.html
    <mat-sidenav-content>
        <div class="content">
            <ng-content select="[outlet]"></ng-content>
        </div>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
```

So when I navigate to `/admin/editor` everything works as expected: I can see the `ShellComponent` and the `EditorComponent` is shown in the right place. The problem starts inside the `EditorComponent`. This component contains a `<profile></profile>` where I want to display the `<view-profile></view-profile>` or `<edit-profile></edit-profile>` component using the outlet named `profile` (as you can see in the `EditorRoutingModule` configuration. Here the code:

```
   // editor.component.html
   <profile></profile>

   // profile.component.html
   <router-outlet name="profile"></router-outlet>

   // profile.component.ts
   ngOnInit(): void {
      this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { profile: ['view-profile'] } }], { relativeTo: this.route });
   }
```

The `ProfileComponent` loads but I don't see the `<view-profile></view-profile>` as I expect. Inspecting the HTML I can see the profile outlet where I expect it.

Any suggestion about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work but I don't know if it should be like this or if it's a workaround. Anyway, I gave a `path` to the root of the `EditorRoutingModule` and added the named routes as its children, like this:

```
  const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: 'outlets',
      component: EditorComponent,
      children: [
        { path: 'view-profile', component: ViewProfileComponent, outlet: 'profile' },
        { path: 'edit-profile', component: EditProfileComponent, outlet: 'profile' },
      ],
    },
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'outlets', pathMatch: 'full' },
  ];
```

I don't like it completely because my route looks like `/admin/editor/outlets/(profile:edit-profile)`, is it possible to achieve the same result without the `/outlets/` part in the route?

Answer (score 0):

Had to leave the path property empty like this..

```
{ path: '', component: ViewProfileComponent, outlet: 'view-profile', pathMatch: 'full' }
```